# A RenderFlex overflowed by 147 pixels on the bottom. (It's not a simple solution.)

Tags: android, flutter, dart

#### Assumption and what I want to achieve

I want to make it so that after inputting into the TextField of the TodoAddPage class, it will be displayed in the TodoListPage class like a "TODO list".

#### Problems and error messages that are occurring

It looks like the following image.
! image description

#### The corresponding source code.

````
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // app name
      title: 'My Todo App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // theme color
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      // display the list list screen
      home: TodoListPage(),
    );
  }
}

// Widget for list list screen
class MyTodoApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'My Todo App',

        // App name
        theme: ThemeData(
          // theme color
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        // Display the list list screen
        home:
        TodoListPage()
    );
  }
}

// Widget for list list screen
class TodoListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TodoListPageState createState() => _TodoListPageState();
}

class _TodoListPageState extends State<TodoListPage> {
  // Todo list data
  List<String> todoList = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double _height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(


      // Display the AppBar and set the title
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('List of Lists'),

      ),
      body: Container(
        height: _height,
        width: _width,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              const Color(0xffe4a972).withOpacity(0.6),
              const Color(0xff9941d8).withOpacity(0.6), const Color(0xff9941d8).withOpacity(0.6),
            ],
            begin: Alignment.topRight,
            end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          ),
        ),

        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: todoList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Card(

              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(todoList[index]),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),


      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          // "push" to transition to new screen
          // receive the value passed from the add list screen
          final newListText = await Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
              // specify the list add screen as the destination screen
              return TodoAddPage();
            }),
          );
          if (newListText ! = null) () {
            // note that newListText will be null if we cancel it
            setState(() {
              // add list
              todoList.add(newListText);
            });
          };
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      // Create a ListView based on the data
    );
  }
}
// Widget for list add screen
class TodoAddPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TodoAddPageState createState() => _TodoAddPageState();
}

class _TodoAddPageState extends State<TodoAddPage> {
  // Have the input text as data
  String _text = '';

  // Widget to display based on the data
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
      Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Add list'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        // Add margins
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(64),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            // Display the input text
            Text(_text, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
            const SizedBox(height: 8),
            // Input text
            TextField(
              // receive the value of the input text (value is the input text)
              onChanged: (String value) {
                // notify that the data has changed (refresh the screen)
                setState(() {
                  // change the data
                  _text = value;
                });
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 8),
            Container(
              // expand to full width
              width: double.infinity,
              // add list button
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // "pop" to go back to the previous screen
                  // pass the data from the "pop" argument to the previous screen
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(_text);
                },
                child: Text('add list', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 8),
            Container(
              // expand to full width
              width: double.infinity,
              // cancel button
              child: TextButton(
                // what to do when the button is clicked
                onPressed: () {
                  // "pop" to go back to the previous screen
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                child: Text('cancel'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
      );
  }
}


```

### Things I've tried

I've enclosed the Widget in a SingleChildScrollView.
However, when I press the button, it goes blank.
````

Comment: I'll add a note about the errors.
First, I get the error "A RenderFlex overflowed by 147 pixels on the bottom.
First, I get an error "A RenderFlex overflowed by 147 pixels on the bottom." I tried to fix it with "SingleChildScrollView" but the screen just goes blank.

Comment: Hello friend, I do not experience the error when running on my emulator. Can you specify the device version of the emulator?